# Установка Yii2 advanced на Windows 10

Tags: yii2, composer

пробовал устанавливать 2-мя способами: в первом требует ввести токен с Github, а во 2-м из архива пишет что:
"В файл config/web.php нужно прописать секретный ключ в значение cookieValidationKey (при установке через Composer это происходит автоматически)" 
вот только где находиться этот файл и какой именно ключ необходимо ввести?

Код установки XAMPP

user@DESKTOP-OKASEM6 MINGW64 /d/xampp/htdocs/yii.loc
$ composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"
Changed current directory to C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/Composer
Deprecation Notice: The Composer\Package\LinkConstraint\MultiConstraint class is                          deprecated, use Composer\Semver\Constraint\MultiConstraint instead. in phar://C                         :/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Package/LinkConstrain                         t/MultiConstraint.php:17
Deprecation Notice: The Composer\Package\LinkConstraint\LinkConstraintInterface                          interface is deprecated, use Composer\Semver\Constraint\ConstraintInterface inst                         ead. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Packa                         ge/LinkConstraint/LinkConstraintInterface.php:17

[ReflectionException]
  Class Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\NpmRepository does not exist

[ErrorException]
  Declaration of Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\AbstractAssetsRepository::w                         hatProvides(Composer\DependencyResolv
  er\Pool $pool, $name) should be compatible with Composer\Repository\ComposerRe                         pository::whatProvides(Composer\Depen
  dencyResolver\Pool $pool, $name, $bypassFilters = false)

global  []...

user@DESKTOP-OKASEM6 MINGW64 /d/xampp/htdocs/yii.loc
$ composer create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced./2.0.12
Deprecation Notice: The Composer\Package\LinkConstraint\MultiConstraint class is                          deprecated, use Composer\Semver\Constraint\MultiConstraint instead. in phar://C                         :/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Package/LinkConstrain                         t/MultiConstraint.php:17
Deprecation Notice: The Composer\Package\LinkConstraint\LinkConstraintInterface                          interface is deprecated, use Composer\Semver\Constraint\ConstraintInterface inst                         ead. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Packa                         ge/LinkConstraint/LinkConstraintInterface.php:17

[InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced./2.0.12 with stability stable.

create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--s] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [

user@DESKTOP-OKASEM6 MINGW64 /d/xampp/htdocs/yii.loc
$

Возможно, что-то не так с плагином asset - пробовал командой composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.3.1" может, его ещё отдельно надо как-то устанавливать?
 уже 2 дня мучаюсь с этим. нормально скачались файлы только через архив и там есть папка vendor, но файл config/web.php нигде не найти. а через Composer полный треш..
если вводить команды со словом PHAR - то открывается просто редактор с файлом.

[image: Установка XAMPP]

Comment: composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin" (http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/62276-yii2-composer-is-broken/)

Comment: сейчас пробую установить через архив. после команды php-init файлы вроде инициализировались и теперь нужно main.php (для advanced)  в секции request указать
'cookieValidationKey' => '', // в кавычках  ключ                              
Только вот  файл main.php есть в директории D:\sites\yii\common\config но там нет секции "request"   <?php
return [
    'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
    ],
];

Comment: и ещё main.php есть в: 
D:\sites\yii\backend\views\layouts 
D:\sites\yii\console\config D:\sites\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-debug\views\layouts 
D:\sites\yii\backend\config 
D:\sites\yii\frontend\config 
D:\sites\yii\frontend\views\layouts 
D:\sites\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-debug\views\layouts D:\sites\yii\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-gii\views\layouts

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте команду

```
composer global require fxp/composer-asset-plugin --no-plugins
```

Comment: У меня сработало только после добавления токена в https://github.com/settings/tokens и передача его для инсталляции. Адрес для добавления был в консоли.

Comment: после команд  composer global require fxp/composer-asset-plugin --no-plugins и  composer create-project yiisoft/yii-app-advanced./2.0.12 в папке появилось только 2 файла create-project и global